# Django CSRF token missing or incorrect for FormView

Tags: django, django-generic-views, django-csrf

I am new to Django and following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEktHo5-kBY&hd=1) to add a Like button to a module. I have views like this:

```
class VoteFormView(FormView):
    form_class = VoteForm

    def form_valid(self, form):


        pic = get_object_or_404(UserPic, pk=form.data["pic"])
        user = self.request.user
        prev_votes = Vote.objects.filter(voter=user, pic=pic)
        has_voted = (prev_votes.count() > 0)



        if not has_voted:
            # add vote
            Vote.objects.create(voter=user, pic=pic)
            print("voted")
        else:
            # delete vote
            prev_votes[0].delete()
            print("unvoted")

        return render_to_response('userpics/photo.html',
                                      {'pic':pic})

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print("invalid")
        return render_to_response('userpics/photo.html',
                                      {'pic':pic})
```

In photo.html I have:

```
{% if pic %}

<form method="post" action="/photo/vote/" class="vote_form">
    <li> [{{ pic.votes }}]
   {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" id="id_pic" name="pic" class="hidden_id" value="{{ pic.pk }}" />
  <input type="hidden" id="id_voter" name="voter" class="hidden_id" value="{{ user.pk }}" />
  <button>Like</button>

</form>

 <img class="pic" src="/static/assets/{{pic}}" />


{% endif %}
```

When I click the like link on a photo page for the second time, I get this error:

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

I tried:

```
return render_to_response('userpics/photo.html',
                              {'pic':pic,},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But since this view does not have a 'request' object, the above statement causes an error too. So I'm not sure how to implement csrf for this view and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can access to the request using `self.request`, so try:

```
return render_to_response('userpics/photo.html',
                          {'pic':pic,},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(self.request))
```